# How to calculate the maximum of last 5 years in panel data

Tags: stata

I have panel data. I am interested to calculate the maximum of one variable (Var_C) in the last 5 years.I tried several different functions and loop but did not manage to get what I wanted.

Comment: Search Statalist for mentions of `tsegen` (SSC). On this site do please read and act on http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reproducible example. You must install `tsegen` with `ssc install tsegen` before you can use it.

```
webuse grunfeld 
tsset
tsegen max_invest = rowmax(L.(0/4).invest) 

list *invest if company == 1
     +-------------------+
     | invest   max_in~t |
     |-------------------|
  1. |  317.6      317.6 |
  2. |  391.8      391.8 |
  3. |  410.6      410.6 |
  4. |  257.7      410.6 |
  5. |  330.8      410.6 |
     |-------------------|
  6. |  461.2      461.2 |
  7. |    512        512 |
  8. |    448        512 |
  9. |  499.6        512 |
 10. |  547.5      547.5 |
     |-------------------|
 11. |  561.2      561.2 |
 12. |  688.1      688.1 |
 13. |  568.9      688.1 |
 14. |  529.2      688.1 |
 15. |  555.1      688.1 |
     |-------------------|
 16. |  642.9      688.1 |
 17. |  755.9      755.9 |
 18. |  891.2      891.2 |
 19. | 1304.4     1304.4 |
 20. | 1486.7     1486.7 |
     +-------------------+
```

If the definition of the last 5 years doesn't include the current year, but means over the previous 5 years, the syntax would be `L.(1/5)`. If you want a minimum of 5 years in each window, there is syntax to match.